# C# WMI privileges

Tags: c#, wmi, system, privileges

I have searched through numerous questions about how to convert VBS to C# and all that good stuff.

The issue that I'm having is that with the VBS code (see below) when the process is executed on the remote machine it's run with the SYSTEM account.
When I execute with C# it's run with my credentials (or whomever runs the C# program).
The VBS seems to be more reliable in getting remote installs to go through which is what i need it for.

I wanted to switch to C# so I could make a more user friendly GUI for the program.
Anyone know how to get C# to run WMI with the SYSTEM account?

VBS Code:

```
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set objScheduledJob = objWMIService.Get("Win32_ScheduledJob")
Set objSWbemDateTime = CreateObject("WbemScripting.SWbemDateTime")

'add the scheduled job to be run
objSWbemDateTime.SetVarDate(DateAdd(INTERVAL, MINUTES, Now()))
errReturn = objScheduledJob.Create(strCommand, objSWbemDateTime.Value, False, 0, 0, True, intJobID)
```

C# code:

```
static public int RemoteAdmin(string remoteMachine, string runFile)
{
    try
    {
        ManagementPath run = new ManagementPath(@"\\" + remoteMachine + @"\root\cimv2:Win32_process");
        ManagementClass man = new ManagementClass(run);

        man.InvokeMethod("Create", new Object[] { runFile });
        return 0;
    }
    catch
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error in remote execution");
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you look at the ConnectionOptions class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably idiot error on my part but the error I was getting was because I didn't specify a time (UTC format) for it to start the scheduled job

```
    ConnectionOptions connOptions = new ConnectionOptions();
    connOptions.Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate;
    connOptions.Authentication = AuthenticationLevel.PacketPrivacy;
    connOptions.EnablePrivileges = true;
    ManagementScope manScope = new ManagementScope(String.Format(@"\\" + remoteMachine + @"\ROOT\CIMV2"), connOptions);
    manScope.Connect();
    ObjectGetOptions objectGetOptions = new ObjectGetOptions();
    ManagementPath managementPath = new ManagementPath("Win32_ScheduledJob");
    ManagementClass processClass = new ManagementClass(manScope, managementPath, objectGetOptions);
    ManagementBaseObject inParams = processClass.GetMethodParameters("Create");
    inParams["Command"] = runFile;
    string StartTime = DateTimetoUTC(DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(1));
    inParams["StartTime"] = StartTime;
    ManagementBaseObject outParams = processClass.InvokeMethod("Create", inParams, null);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to setup the [`ConnectionOptions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.connectionoptions.aspx)

```
ConnectionOptions wmiConnOpts = new ConnectionOptions();
wmiConnOpts.Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate;
wmiConnOpts.Authentication = System.Management.AuthenticationLevel.Default;
wmiConnOpts.EnablePrivileges = true;

ManagementScope wmiLoc = 
   new ManagementScope(String.Format(@"\\{0}\root\cimv2", remoteMachine ),
      wmiConnOpts);
ManagementPath wmiProcPath = new ManagementPath("Win32_ScheduledJob");
ManagementClass wmiProc = new ManagementClass(wmiLoc, wmiProcPath, null);
wmiProc.InvokeMethod("Create", new Object[] { runFile });
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick reply. I must confess I'm not 100% great with C# (it's probably obvious). I'm getting an error in the line:

Comment: sorry... "wmiProc.InvokeMethod("Create", new Object[] {runFile}); The error states that there is an invalid parameter. runFile at the time = "cmd.exe /c taskkill /f /im iexplore.exe"

Comment: Any ideas why the above code would have an invalid parameter error when run and passed a hostname and "cmd.exe /c taskkill /f /im iexplore.exe"... also tried passing several other commands such as an msi install, regular exe install, and regedit work. All failed with the same message during debug.